# Is the condition in this property setter valid?

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I am refactoring a number of our projects for reuse with one of our clients and I'm hoping to sanity check a decision to rewrite one of the property setters.

I have seen this implementation a few times in our codebase, but as it was written by a developer who no longer works here, I can't ask him about it.

It goes as follows:

```
private double _myProperty;

public double MyProperty
{
    get { return _myProperty; }
    set
    {
        if (!(Math.Abs(_myProperty - value) < double.Epsilon))
        {
            _myProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();   
        }
    }
}
```

I am quite familiar with writing the following syntax for property setters:

```
if (value != _myProperty)
```

But in the first example above I have been wondering if I am missing something. I know that the Math.Abs calculation is giving me the difference between 'value' and the current value of '_myProperty', but why the comparison with double.Epsilon? According to both IntelliSense and MSDN, double.Epsilon "represents the smallest positive double value that is greater than zero". So surely the comparison could just as easily be:

```
if (Math.Abs(_myProperty - value) > 0)
```

Was the previous developer just being unnecessarily complicated, or am I missing some little nuance of C# I haven't covered yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odds are what they *meant* to do was to use some Epsilon value other than `double.Epsilon`.  As you noted, `double.Epsilon` is the smallest value that a `double` can represent, and no two different doubles can be closer than `double.Epsilon`, and as a result, their code is functionally identical to just checking if the difference is equal to zero, which is functionally identical to just doing a regular equality check of the two doubles.

The general idea behind the logic is to have numbers that are "close enough" to each other to be considered equal, where "close enough" is a value that is based on the significant figures of the numbers that you're dealing with.  Either they intended to use `SomeBusinessObject.Epsilon` that represents the precision of the values that you're working with, or they were simply writing cargo cult code and didn't understand what they were doing.

Comment: Thanks, I will update it to use a more appropriate value for the Epsilon

Answer (score 2):

Comparing the equality of 2 double values using Epsilon is certainly more correct but in most cases it is overkill and can easily be mis-coded as your example proves.

the difference between two doubles can never be less than Epsilon without being zero as you indicate.  So to be effective (i,e. to do something more meaningful than a simple equality test) the difference must be <= Epsilon.

```
if (!(Math.Abs(_myProperty - value) <= double.Epsilon))
```

This allows a 1-bit wobble in the two values.  I think you will burn up more CPU cycles than save them.  Certainly for accepting user entry this test is complete overkill.

What I have done in the past is define my own Epsilon that has real world meaning.  So for example if I am monitoring real time temperature measurements, I am not interested in changes less than say 1E-6 deg F and so I will define Epsilon to be that.